# Lazy Load youtube video 1 click to load and play

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I am using this code and is working perfect to use images to lazyload YT videos:

```
( function() {

var youtube = document.querySelectorAll( ".youtube" );

for (var i = 0; i < youtube.length; i++) {

var source = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ youtube[i].dataset.embed +"/sddefault.jpg";

var image = new Image();
    image.src = source;
    image.addEventListener( "load", function() {
      youtube[ i ].appendChild( image );
    }( i ) );

    youtube[i].addEventListener( "click", function() {

      var iframe = document.createElement( "iframe" );

          iframe.setAttribute( "frameborder", "0" );
          iframe.setAttribute( "allowfullscreen", "" );
          iframe.setAttribute( "src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+ this.dataset.embed +"?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1" );

          this.innerHTML = "";
          this.appendChild( iframe );
    } );  
};

} )();
```

However requieres 2 clicks 1 to load the video and then 1 to play the video in order to work. Is there any way I can use this same code with just 1 click to play YouTube Videos?

And is possible to make this to work also with Vimeo Videos?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
iframe.setAttribute( "allow", "autoplay" );
```